# Gradle: one build type based on another

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 4 build types in Android Studio:

```
release
debug
kindle
kindle_debug
```

How is it possible to set the both kindle tasks to use the same data from release/debug and just changing some properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `initWith` to inherit from another BuildType like in this example:

```
android {
[...]
   buildTypes {            
            debug {
                debuggable true
                buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_V2", "false"
            }
            debugV2 {
                initWith debug
                buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_V2", "true"
                applicationIdSuffix ".v2"
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Then select debugV2 from `Build Variants` in Android Studio.

See also the docs here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

Comment: @mars3142, you should accept this answer, it's correct.